# even if torque is constant is angular impulse theory true?

Tags: electromagnetism

I came across a question of electromagnetic induction wherein a point charge Q was revolving with a constant angular speed "w". Soon after a time varying magnetic field was switched on perpendicular to the xy plane in which the charge was revolving defined as B=(Bo)t for 1 sec.
Now calculate the change in magnetic moment during this time interval.
I applied angular impulse theory, but my teacher told me that it is not valid as the rate of change is constant. Can anyone explain?